# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"updateInstock\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to adjust my `countInStock` based off of `qty` ordered. In my `PlaceOrderScreen.js`, I have `items = item.map(product => ({ _id: product._id, countInStock: product.countInStock, qty: product.qty, new:(product.countInStock - product.qty) }))` where `item = cart.carItems`. I'm trying to get this to my backend in my `productRouter.js`, so that I can update my products based off of their new countInStock, but I'm getting `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"updateInstock\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\"`. I'm unsure of why this is happening, and I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {createOrder} from '../actions/orderActions';
import {updateInstock} from '../actions/productActions';
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants';

export default function PlaceOrderScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
    props.history.push('/payment');
  }
  const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
  const { loading, success, error, order } = orderCreate;
  
  const item = cart.cartItems
  const items = item.map(product => ({ _id: product._id, countInStock: product.countInStock, qty: product.qty, new:(product.countInStock - product.qty) }))
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const placeOrderHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems }));
    dispatch(updateInstock(items));
  };
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, order, props.history, success]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-1">
          <div className="card card-body">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  ...
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeOrderHandler}
                  className="primary block"
                  disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                >
                  Place Order
                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

productActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
    PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_FAIL,
  
} from '../constants/productConstants';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants/app.constants';

export const updateInstock = (items) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_REQUEST, payload: items });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/api/products/updateInstock`, items, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATEINSTOCK_FAIL, error: message });
    }
};
```

productRouter.js

```
productRouter.put(
    '/updateInstock',
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body.items)
    })
  );
```

`console.log(req.body.items)` is not showing data in the terminal.

Comment: The error is in backend. Show the code of `productRouter.js` of relevant route.

Comment: @charchit, I added the relevant backend, but I really don't have anything there yet

Comment: What is productId? and  If you want the items from frontend, you need `req.body.items`

Comment: I just had ```productId``` to get the ```_id``` for the products, but I got ride of it because it wasn't helpful. Ya, I thought I would need ```req.body.items```, so I tried ```console.log(req.body.items)``` in ```productRouter.js```, but I'm not getting anything, and I'm still getting the ```cast to objectId...``` error.

Comment: It won't show because you need to pass an object. `Axios.put(url, {items},...`. Cast error occurs because mongodb need `_id like 6271887fa31bd514b6a2c2a5`, If you provide anything else cast error will occur. I dk if you want to update many products or just one.

Comment: Oh, okay! I'm trying to update as many products as are in ```items```. ```Items``` is an array with ```_id```s, ```new``` (new ```countInStock```), etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245350/discussion-between-charchit-and-gigi101).